# Javascript Templateproject "strange" new Function call im not understand

Tags: javascript, node.js

For my new Project (JavaScript on Node.js) I have to use a Templateproject.

There I found the following Code Snipped. I want to understand what they doing here. For me it makes no sense.

```
....    
1    lines[lines.length - 1] = lines[lines.length - 1].trim().replace(/};$/, '}');
2        words = lines.join('\n');
3        var resultFunc = new Function('return ' + words + ';');
4
5        return resultFunc();
6    } catch (e) {
....
```

Why is in Line 4 that `"new Function"` and what happen here?

Thanks

Comment: `new Function` creates a new function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: yes i know. To make my question more clear. Why they fill this String concat in the Function and then call this Function on return statement? When im correct then do this funktion only return words again?

Comment: No, the value of `words` is evaluated as JavaScript code. If it retuned just `words`, the code would be `new Function('return words')`. Why they are doing this is impossible to answer without knowing what `words` contains and what the purpose of the function is that this code is contained in.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you so much for your fast help.

Comment: For completeness: I have checked the code above this Snippet -> words contains code :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, functions are also objects of Function class.

Below is what it means...

## Original

```
//if words = 'some_string'
var resultFunc = new Function('return ' + words + ';');
```

## Equivalent to

```
//if words = 'somestring'
var resultFunc = function() {
    return 'somestring';
}
```

Comment: This is just how they wanted to implement, as we do inline css sometimes.. they did it same way.

Comment: That’s not quite right. The function does not return the value of `words`. The value of `words` is evaluated as JavaScript code.

Comment: Yeah you are right!! answered it quite quickly, missed that part

Answer (score 0):

> Use `new Function()` in place of `eval()`.

`new Function()` is generally used as an alternate for `eval()` function. Using eval function is considered to be a bad practice because of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) reasons. Now, when you pass a string as a parameter to `new Function()` it would actually create a function with the code in that string as the body of the function. Therefore you can think of line `var resultFunc = new Function('return ' + words + ';');` as:

```
var words = "someValue";
var resultFunc = function () {
  return "someValue";
}
```

Comment: As I already mentioned on the other answer, the function does not return `words`.

Comment: Also notice that most of the reasons why `eval` is bad applies to `new Function` as well

Comment: @Bergi Most! but not all. :)